# How could replace "ls" command of win10 with gnu's?

Tags: windows, ls

I installed gnu-coreutils for windows with scoop as:

```
PS C:\Users\gaowei> scoop info coreutils
Name: coreutils
Description: A collection of GNU utilities such as bash, make, gawk and grep
Version: 5.97.3
Website: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys
License: GPL-2.0-only (https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-2.0-only.html)
```

However, the default command of "ls" stayed unchanged of native windows' utility.

```
PS C:\Users\gaowei> ls |head -n 10
Directory: C:\Users\gaowei

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         2020/8/26     10:01                .config
da----         2020/8/26     15:41                .doom.d
d-----         2020/8/26     13:11                .emacs.d
PS C:\Users\gaowei>
```

How could replace windows' command of "ls" with gnu's?

the gnu ls installed as:

```
PS C:\Users\gaowei> which scoop ls
C:/Users/gaowei/scoop/shims/scoop.cmd
ls
```

Comment: I'd advise you first to check if you have a GNU `ls` installed (e.g. `which scoop` to have an idea where the binaries are located), and go on from there.

Comment: @Dominique it returned as `C:/Users/gaowei/scoop/shims/scoop.cmd
ls`.

Comment: Windows doesn't have an `ls` command. PowerShell sets an `ls` alias for `Get-ChildItem`, which is a silly thing to do since the normal POSIX command-line options aren't supported and the output is totally different. You can remove the alias with `remove-alias ls`.